# Analytics enhanced e-commerce - Service account

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm measuring the data for a client's website using google analytics enhanced e-commerce tool.

I have set up a service account using HelloAnalytics API to show the measured data on their website. Using this I have been able to show the client data such as page sessions, page views, etc.

I can't seem to find a way to show them any data from the enhanced e-commerce tool. For instance, I want to show them the number of clicks on products from a certain product list.

Is there any way to do this? Any help is appreciated, I have been stuck on this for days.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the API version you are using, there's a list of dimensions and metrics, which are supported by the reporting API. For V4, you can find the whole list [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets).

[This](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#q=product&cats=user,session,traffic_sources,adwords,goal_conversions,platform_or_device,geo_network,system,social_activities,page_tracking,content_grouping,internal_search,site_speed,app_tracking,event_tracking,ecommerce,social_interactions,user_timings,exceptions,content_experiments,custom_variables_or_columns,time,doubleclick_campaign_manager,audience,adsense,ad_exchange,doubleclick_for_publishers,doubleclick_for_publishers_backfill,lifetime_value_and_cohorts,channel_grouping,related_products,doubleclick_bid_manager,doubleclick_search) is the list of product related items. Based on your example, Product List Clicks should be available via API as described ([here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=ecommerce&jump=ga_productlistclicks)).

Although not that of the latest version, but a description of filters is available [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters). This will be required, if you want to narrow your query to certain products.